# client property undefined in SignalR Move Shape demo under IIS 7.5?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, signalr

I'm having trouble getting the SignalR demo Move Shape working on IIS 7.5. It works for me on my development PC under IIS express and Visual Studio 2013.

I'm currently copying the Move.html file and /scripts from the project to the wwwroot directory on the IIS 7.5 PC.

When I load the Move.html on the IIS PC from `http:// localhost/Move.html`, I get the following error in the javascript:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

which is the result of my previous line `var moveShapeHub = $.connection.moveShapeHub,` returning moveShapeHub as undefined.

Move.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SignalR MoveShape Demo</title>
    <style>
        #shape {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #FF0000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var moveShapeHub = $.connection.moveShapeHub,
                $shape = $("#shape"),
                // Send a maximum of 10 messages per second
                // (mouse movements trigger a lot of messages)
                messageFrequency = 10,
                // Determine how often to send messages in
                // time to abide by the messageFrequency
                updateRate = 1000 / messageFrequency,
                shapeModel = {
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0
                },
                moved = false;
            moveShapeHub.client.updateShape = function (model) {
                shapeModel = model;
                // Gradually move the shape towards the new location (interpolate)
                // The updateRate is used as the duration because by the time
                // we get to the next location we want to be at the "last" location
                // We also clear the animation queue so that we start a new
                // animation and don't lag behind.
                $shape.animate(shapeModel, { duration: updateRate, queue: false });
            };
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $shape.draggable({
                    drag: function () {
                        shapeModel = $shape.offset();
                        moved = true;
                    }
                });
                // Start the client side server update interval
                setInterval(updateServerModel, updateRate);
            });
            function updateServerModel() {
                // Only update server if we have a new movement
                if (moved) {
                    moveShapeHub.server.updateModel(shapeModel);
                    moved = false;
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

    <div id="shape" />
</body>
</html>
```

So it is able to find the /signalr/hubs and the other  definitions but can't resolve the hub under IIS 7.5, but it works under IIS express.

Am I missing some setup under IIS 7.5?

What setup steps are needed under IIS 7.5?

Can this work under IIS 7.5?

Here is the hub code (straight from the demo):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MoveShapeDemo
{
    public class Broadcaster
    {
        private readonly static Lazy<Broadcaster> _instance =
            new Lazy<Broadcaster>(() => new Broadcaster());
        // We're going to broadcast to all clients a maximum of 25 times per second
        private readonly TimeSpan BroadcastInterval =
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(40);
        private readonly IHubContext _hubContext;
        private Timer _broadcastLoop;
        private ShapeModel _model;
        private bool _modelUpdated;
        public Broadcaster()
        {
            // Save our hub context so we can easily use it 
            // to send to its connected clients
            _hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MoveShapeHub>();
            _model = new ShapeModel();
            _modelUpdated = false;
            // Start the broadcast loop
            _broadcastLoop = new Timer(
                BroadcastShape,
                null,
                BroadcastInterval,
                BroadcastInterval);
        }
        public void BroadcastShape(object state)
        {
            // No need to send anything if our model hasn't changed
            if (_modelUpdated)
            {
                // This is how we can access the Clients property 
                // in a static hub method or outside of the hub entirely
                _hubContext.Clients.AllExcept(_model.LastUpdatedBy).updateShape(_model);
                _modelUpdated = false;
            }
        }
        public void UpdateShape(ShapeModel clientModel)
        {
            _model = clientModel;
            _modelUpdated = true;
        }
        public static Broadcaster Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return _instance.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MoveShapeHub : Hub
    {
        // Is set via the constructor on each creation
        private Broadcaster _broadcaster;
        public MoveShapeHub()
            : this(Broadcaster.Instance)
        {
        }
        public MoveShapeHub(Broadcaster broadcaster)
        {
            _broadcaster = broadcaster;
        }
        public void UpdateModel(ShapeModel clientModel)
        {
            clientModel.LastUpdatedBy = Context.ConnectionId;
            // Update the shape model within our broadcaster
            _broadcaster.UpdateShape(clientModel);
        }
    }
    public class ShapeModel
    {
        // We declare Left and Top as lowercase with 
        // JsonProperty to sync the client and server models
        [JsonProperty("left")]
        public double Left { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("top")]
        public double Top { get; set; }
        // We don't want the client to get the "LastUpdatedBy" property
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    }

}
```

And here is the Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MoveShapeDemo.Startup))]
namespace MoveShapeDemo
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your hub code?

Comment: I've added the Hub and Startup code. This code is straight from the demo and works fine on my development PC running under IIS express. I just can't get it working under IIS 7.5 on the deployment PC.

Comment: Once you launch your site could you check to see if your hub proxy is getting loaded for /Signalr/hubs?

Comment: What do I check to see if /signalr/hubs is launched? Using Chrome developer tools I can see that the /signalr/hubs has a status of '200 OK' in the network tab. Under the Sources tab if I stop on line 20 `var moveShapeHub = $.connection.moveShapeHub,` I see that `$.connection.moveShapeHub` is undefined so maybe it is not loaded. How do I get it loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Once you launch your site could you check to see if your hub proxy is getting loaded for /Signalr/hubs. Just hit your URL http:// localhost/SignalR/hubs.You should see the SignalR generated proxy (unless you have turned it off in your Global.asax which it does not look like it because you were able to hit it in IISExpress.

If you can bring up the hub proxy up then just change the following in your HTML, from

```
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

                    to

    <script src="http:/localhost/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

You can learn more about SignalR [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr) - really good resource on everything that is signalR.

### UPDATE:

You say that when running in visual studio and IIS expresss your Move.html works just fine. What else is in the Visual Studio solution or project as part of Move.html? You have C# code for your hub, have you deployed that? The use of /signalr/hubs suggests that Move.html and the hub are part of the same project, but in your original query you say that you just moved Move.html. You would have to publish the entire project and move that published version to the wwwroot folder. For publishing steps look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983453(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I don't have a Global.asax file. I see the http://lcoalhost/SignalR/hubs creates a differnent proxy (for another SignalR web app I tried and get net::Err_Connection_Reset errors after that page loads). So for this example no SignalR Proxies, no global.asax, it all works great when running under VS 2013 but can't be deployed...  
The link you sent is the base SignalR link, where I got the sample I'm trying to run, any pointers to where I can find out more about successfully deploying it on IIS?